# Open a modal of vue-js-modal from outside a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-js-modal

We are using `vue-js-modal` in our project, and I want to open a modal from code which isn't in a vue component. The documentation only indicate how to use the API from a component. There is a way to manipulate `vue-js-modal` from anywhere ?

The X problem, I want to warn user with a popup when a router error occure in `router.onError((error)=>...)`

Comment: You can use the vue EventBus to raise an event and handle it in your component.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for your suggestion. Instantiating a new "Vue" object, allow me to access the "$modal" entrypoint for vue-js-modal API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating a new Vue object, allow to acces the $modal API entrypoint :

```
const vue = new Vue();
vue.$modal.show({template:'<div>Error during loading...</div>'});
```

Comment: Awesome! you got the solution :)